# Dynamically let the user see what my site would look like on different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have designed a site that is responsive with foundation 4. I would like to have 3 buttons:
[image: buttons]
 that would force the browser to display what the site would look like at different screen resolutions (keeping the browser maximized) when pressed. Kinda like screenfly...   Is this possible ?,

thanks, Jillian.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed an `iframe` on your page and dynamically change its dimensions on button click.